# What's a "good" helpful flags percentage?

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-history, flag-ban

The flag suspension that [triggers on 25% flags declined in the last 7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405) could possibly impact me depending on how exactly things drain from "waiting for review" vs land into "helpful" on a given day.

For the month that I've been tracking, I haven't dropped below 97 percent. I'll always try to be more accurate on my flags.

But I'm curious about these things:

- Do we have graphs of helpful percentages for users of various reputations? For example

  [0-499, 500-999, 1000-1999, 2000-9999, 10000-24999, 25000+]
- The data on total flags and total helpful flags is not available in SEDE? Leaving no way for a user to graph this data?

[image: Your flagging history]

Comment: Anything above NaN

Comment: Post flags include flags for closure when you're below 3k rep, which can result in having a whole lot more pending flags than the avg user above 3k has due to how slow moving the close queue typically is. Therefore, the kinds of posts you're looking to flag for closure can weigh heavily on how... "helpful" your numbers turn out to be. when taking into account that this includes closure flags... i wouldn't put any weight behind that number.

Comment: Ones I should specifically avoid in that case? Others that should be safe?

Comment: You'd want to focus on cases that will actually result in closure, of course. That's a difficult thing to figure out and only really comes with experience here. Don't let this number dissuade you from flagging for closure when you think it's warranted.

Comment: @JamesRisner If you feel a question should be closed, then flag/vote for closure. The vast majority of time, if those flags are not marked "helpful", then they will be marked as "disputed" or they will "age away". Neither "disputed" nor "aged away" affect flag stats.

Comment: I hovering between 90 and 140 waiting normal? High? Low?

Comment: @JamesRisner: As others have said, it depends on which type of flags you have pending. Closure: Not that bad, 90 custom moderator flags: probably too much.

Comment: I rarely use custom mod flags. I have 1 custom, 2 duplicates, and the rest are close based on opinion, need details, not and answer, etc.

Comment: IMO, you really shouldn't put all that much importance on your helpful % *as a number*. Try to learn from the flags which end up being "declined" what things shouldn't be flagged, or, at least, not flagged in the way you did. As you gain more experience flagging and understand better what sorts of things should be flagged, the percentage of your flags which will be "helpful" will naturally increase. But, *please* don't choose to not flag something which you think really does need moderator attention because you're concerned that your helpful percentage might drop by a small amount.

Comment: As to number of flags waiting, the number of flags in the moderator flag queue is really high at the moment, so there are a *lot* more pending flags than "normal". That doesn't mean you shouldn't flag. You should still flag. It just means that it might take longer than normal for the flag to be processed, particularly "in need of moderator intervention" flags, which tend to take the most time and effort to handle.

Comment: "*could possibly impact me depending on how exactly things drain*" Yes, I've had this happen before and it's a known bug/unintended edge case. Have a few custom flags outstanding for weeks/months, have 100 helpful flags since then, wait 5 days, cast 1 flag, have the custom flags from the past and the new 1 flag declined by a moderator clearing out the backlog, *et voila*, you're blocked from casting new flags for a while. Especially annoying when the moderators get the outcome wrong :-) The system should base it off of when the flag was raised, not when it was handled/resolved.

Comment: That being said, this is an opinion-based question... really any number can arguably be 'good enough' depending on who you ask and what their personal metrics are. The weight is also going to differ drastically depending on how many total flags you have cast. If you've cast 5 flags, then a 20% or 40% helpful rate isn't all that bad. You're new, still learning, etc. If you have cast 5,000 or 25,000 flags and your helpful rate is that low, then you're probably suspended from flagging indefinitely by the moderators by now :-)

Comment: User script: https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox

Comment: This script might have insight for me. Various flag levels and classifications. https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ModFlaggerStats.user.js